# Create URL Query String to accept Terms & Conditions

Tags: asp.net, vba, forms

I am building a script that is downloading a zip file and placing it on my desktop. The script works fine except the link to the zip file is taking me to a terms and condition site in order to download it.

I have the below form:

```
<form action="https://powhatan.iiie.disa.mil/TOUbanneraccept.asp">
   <input name="HTTP_REFERER" type="hidden" value="http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/compilations/Pages/index.aspx">
   <input name="HTTP_HOST" type="hidden" value="powhatan.iiie.disa.mil">
   <input name="SERVER_NAME" type="hidden" value="powhatan.iiie.disa.mil">
   <input name="URL" type="hidden" value="/TOUbanner.asp">
   <input name="SCRIPT_NAME" type="hidden" value="/TOUbanner.asp">
   <input name="PATH_INFO" type="hidden" value="/TOUbanner.asp">
   <input name="Destination" type="hidden" value="">
   <input name="OriginalURL" type="hidden" value="https://powhatan.iiie.disa.mil/stigs/downloads/zip/FOUO_SRG-STIG_Library_2017_04.zip">
   <input name="RewriteURL" type="hidden" value="">
   <input name="Accept" style="width: 150px;" type="submit" value="I ACCEPT">
</form>
```

I am trying to create a **query string** to accept the webpage terms so that my download will continue but my query string is not working. From what i researched I came up with:

`https://powhatan.iiie.disa.mil/TOUbanneraccept.asp/?HTTP_REFERER=http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/compilations/Pages/index.aspx&HTTP_HOST=powhatan.iiie.disa.mil&SERVER_NAME=powhatan.iiie.disa.mil&URL=/TOUbanner.asp&SCRIPT_NAME=/TOUbanner.asp&OriginalURL=https://powhatan.iiie.disa.mil/stigs/downloads/zip/FOUO_SRG-STIG_Library_2017_04.zip&Accept=I%20ACCEPT`

I even tried

`https://powhatan.iiie.disa.mil/TOUbanneraccept.asp?Accept=I%20ACCEPT`

When I try either one I get a Error 404 page as if the page does not exist. I have to do this because it will be included in a VBA macro.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or what may going on here?

Comment: Could you tell us what you are trying to achieve over all instead of what is not working?

Comment: If this is supposed to be working when you just submit the form as shown - then all you have to do is get the URL from the browser address bar (or via dev tools, network panel, if it should redirect elsewhere automatically), because that simply _is_ what this will send. If that is “not working”, then it might be that the target site expects additional data, such as for example specific cookies, to be set.

Comment: @CBroe Im at the point where it navigates me to a page with this form waiting for me to "accept". I am using `XMLHTTP` to make all of this happen. The response text shows this form.

Comment: generally speaking it seems as though my query string should work but you may be right about the cookies.